# construct histogram on the base of grouped table

Tags: excel, histogram

for instance we have only this information

[image]

generally, i can construct following chart

[image]

but  i have seen chart with following x   formatting
[image]

i have searched a  lot of material on internet, but can't find exactly how can i do it, please recall that we have only grouped information, not original data

Comment: is it possible at all?

Comment: The second graph isn't actually a histogram according to your data. *Histograms* specifically represent the frequency by the area of the "bar" -- your bars would be scaled down by 10. If that isn't what you want, then you might have more luck searching for how to get the right *Bar Chart* rather than *Histogram*

Comment: what about my first chart? is it ok for histogram

Comment: Your first chart clearly isn't a histogram either but I didn't explicitly mention that because you haven't labeled it as a histogram (which you did the second chart)

Comment: so for constructing histogram , i should  have original data and  also bins right and use  excel  function histogram

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is posible but you need one colum more.

Ok lets do it. If we supposing that your clasess column is in range from "A2" to "A(n)"

In colum 3 (C column) in first cell (C2) put this formula

```
=LEFT(A2;SEARCH("-";A2;1)-1)
```

From text ("12 - 21") in cell A2, You wil get text("12") in cell C2.
Then you need to copy this formula to the end of your range. and you will get something like this:

[image]

After that you choose this two column and create column chart.

Like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I can do that but with tricks.

[image]

If you are interested i will do step by step tutorial

Comment: the same i can  do using just typing of   bins, but  66  is not included and that why i asked , any way i understood idea of you  hint

Comment: Ok, but then you put this formula =IF(A2<>"";LEFT(A2;SEARCH("-";A2;1)-1);RIGHT(INDIRECT("A" & ROW(A2)-1);SEARCH("-";INDIRECT("A" & ROW(A2)-1);1)-2))

Comment: but we have  less  length in frequency, i did not understand at all

Comment: we have 6 frequency, without so difficult formula, how can i do same?

Comment: i need to explain to to class to my students

Comment: Ok if you whant i will do it step by step tutorial and i will send you in pdf or something like that.

Comment: any way , my friend,   if i will use  histogram tool from excel, it will be enough right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135694/discussion-between-ir-ir-and-dato-datuashvili).

Comment: i am  there my friend